# What to do with a password entry on screen rotate

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, passwords, bundle

In my application I have a fragment where the user enters a password. This fragment is able to rotate. On rotate I want most of the text fields to be saved and restored using `onSaveInstanceState` and `onActivityCreated`. Normally when I save a password to disk I use a one-way hash to limit the amount of damage which can be done if this info is compromised. However, if the password is only half written, then I can't do a oneway hash... it needs to be recoverable.

So my question: is putting a password in a `Bundle` safe? Or should I simply destroy the value if the fragment gets destroyed? Is the following code a security risk for my users?

```
public override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.PutString("passEditText", _passEditText.Text);
    ...
}

public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        _passEditText.Text = savedInstanceState.GetString("passEditText", "");
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd go for a savedInstanceState. It will be stored in memory only and the same applies for a password field.

Comment: Fragments have a `SaveFragmentInstanceState`... as far as secure? it is **as** secure (or insecure) as any object in memory, including the `EditText` that the partial/full password. Do not serialize the bundle contents to disk or place secure info with a `PersistableBundle`....

Comment: @SushiHangover alright, perfect! Add that as a answer and I'll give you the checkmark!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fragments` have a `SaveFragmentInstanceState` method.

> Save the current instance state of the given Fragment. This can be used later when creating a new instance of the Fragment and adding it to the fragment manager, to have it create itself to match the current state returned here.

Ref: Xamarin: [SaveFragmentInstanceState](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.FragmentManager.SaveFragmentInstanceState/p/Android.App.Fragment/)
Ref: Android: [saveFragmentInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#saveFragmentInstanceState(android.app.Fragment))

**Secure?**

It is as secure, *or insecure*, as any object in memory, including the `EditText` that has the partial/full password within it. Do not serialize the bundle contents to disk or place secure info with a `PersistableBundle` as save it...